# Django - Best way to return in-process text from server to JQuery?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, httpresponse

I'm building what might end up being a web-app / game for a fun side-project. In the app the user has the ability to kick off a server-side function that will do a few processes on the back end. At times this could take a few minutes, so I'm try to work out how to return text from Django to the front end without doing a full 'return' from backend to front. Is there a good way of doing this? I experimented with StreamingHttpResponse, but couldn't figure it out, and am not even sure if it's the right solution. Below is a sample for what my flow looks like.

**Current state**

- User hits button on website and there is an Ajax post call to a
  Django function
- This Django function calls ~4 sub-functions, each doing certain
  processing
- After the completion of all sub-functions (~2 minutes of a static
  front-end), Django returns HTTPResponse of success and triggers a
  refresh of the front end page

**Desired State**

- User hits button on website and there is an Ajax post call to a Django function
- This Django function calls ~4 sub-functions, each doing certain processing
- After the completion of sub-function 1 (~30 seconds), a message is returned to the front-end saying 'X process done, 25% complete for this period'
- After the completion of sub-function 2 (~30 seconds), a message is returned to the front-end saying 'Y process done, 50% complete for this period'... etc for other functions
- After the completion of all sub-functions, Django returns HTTPResponse of success and triggers a refresh of the front end page

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you are trying to make a [full-duplex](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) client-server communication. There are many strategies to make that possible :

- **WebSockets, chat protocols, IoT protocols, and more.**

In `Django`, there is a nice package called `channels` to implement that : https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

- **Answer Lazy URI ressources**

A strategy may be to immediately answer a 
`HTTPResponse` with a URI that will serve the resource when it will be available (with a security *token*). And you can expose another endpoint the Front End can call whenever it wants to know the processing progress, giving its *token*.

- **Asynchronous workloads**

What I understand is that you made the processing **synchronously**, blocking the HTTP answer during all the processing tasks. Actually, with timeout policies, it could be problematic.

And finally, if you think to scale your app, you would probably like to split purely answering HTTP requests, and long-processing workloads.

For that, you may need asynchronous processing, for which `celery` is python natural candidate.